# How to Define and List All Possible Combinations?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

First, very sorry if I don't ask this correctly, I tried searching but I havent found anything that works for what I'm trying to do.

I have 3 dropdowns and I'm just trying to output a list of every single possible combination.

Dropdown 1:

- Male
- Female

Dropdown 2:

- Item1
- Item2

Dropdown 3:

- Beginner
- Intermediate
- Advanced

I'm just trying to be able to define the variables and to output all the combinations for them.. If theres a website that can easily do this that would be as helpful

Comment: There are billions of questions about generating combinations in Javascript; see e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=javascript+combinations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

example using  jQuery `each` nested loops:

```
var listHtml=[];

$('#select1 option').each(function(){
    var mainOpt=$(this).val();    
    $('#select2 option').each(function(){
        var secondOpt=$(this).val();
         $('#select3 option').each(function(){
           listHtml.push(mainOpt +' '+ secondOpt+' ' +$(this).val());              
        });    
    });    
});

$('#list').append('<li>'+  listHtml.join('</li><li>')+'</li>');
```

DEMO http://jsfiddle.net/Xtd3Y/